# Is it acceptable to ask in search of a specific RPG system?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

In light of the removal of the "too localized" close reason, I still feel like I should ask this here.

I'm in search of a specific RPG system whose name I seem to have forgotten, but some details of which I remember. Is it within the scope of the FAQ/help center to ask about it on RPG.SE?

I can't seem to find anything there which directly counters the posting of such a question, but I wanted to verify with the community first.

Edit: This is now a moot point, since I remembered the name of the game I was looking for (Unknown Armies). Still, I'm curious what the answer is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We currently allow game identification questions. Some SEs do not and we would revisit this if we got lots and/or low quality ones. For now, go for it but show you've done research.

Comment: And the tag for it is [tag:product-identification]